# 2 questions about triggers and sameness between 2 tables with using alter schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, schema

I'm not sure how I describe what I want to do but will try anyway, I have 2 tables called XYZ and bckXYZ. bckXYZ is a back up table which created for XYZ. They have same columns but the column order is not the same. When I create a trigger (with asterisk) on XYZ, SQL gives me an error related to column order. As I said their columns are same but the order is not!

I have two options, either I am going to put the column names one by one into the select script instead of using asterisk or will alter the schema of bckXYZ as XYZ.

Question 1: Why trigger needs the same column order? Is it ridicilous?

Question 2: What I need to do is making their schemas look the same so is there any script can do that?

**DOES NOT WORK**

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[XYZ_Ins]
ON [dbo].[XYZ]
FOR  INSERT

AS
INSERT INTO dbo.bckXYZ 
SELECT    inserted.*
FROM         inserted
```

**IT WORKS**

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[XYZ_Ins]
ON [dbo].[XYZ]
FOR  INSERT

AS
INSERT INTO dbo.bckXYZ (a,b,c,d,e)
SELECT    (a, b, c, d, e)
FROM         inserted
```

Comment: The trigger needs the same column order as columns from the insert source and target are mapped by ordinal position not name. You could get away with just one of the insert or select column list but probably best to be explicit and have both anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Why trigger needs the same column order? Is it ridiculous?

No, it's not ridiculous - column names are not *required* in a `select` statement that forms part of an `INSERT ... SELECT` command (columns may be computed and unnamed). All it has to go on (in this case) is column order.

> Question 2: What I need to do is making their schemas look the same so is there any script can do that?

There are no SQL commands to re-arrange columns within a table. If you want to change the order of columns within a table - you can't. If you use e.g. SSMS, what it does behind the scenes is create a *new* table with the adjusted layout, copy all of the data across, delete the old table and rename the new one.

---

All this being said, *even* if the two tables had the same column order, I'd still write out explicit column names in the `INSERT ... SELECT` statement. The only places I'm comfortable with `select *` are a) inside an `EXISTS()` test, and b) in throwaway/scratch queries.

Comment: Completely agree with "...I'd still write out explicit column names in the INSERT ... SELECT statement".

Comment: So if I add a new column into the table, should alter the trigger with adding that column into the select statement.